# How to count elements with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a global controller where I want to count some elements, because after I will scope in a different html.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MainApp')
    .factory('allInventoryFactory', function ($http, $q, myfactory) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: myfactory.URLOperation 
        }).success(function (data) {

            angular.forEach(data, function (datainventary) {
var active = 0;
                   var pending = 0;
                    var desactive = 0;
                    var vodafone = 0;
                var input = datainventary.sites;
                input.forEach(function (input) {

                    if (input.ActivationStatus == 'AC') {
                        console.log("AC");
                        active++;
                    }
                    else if (input.ActivationStatus == 'PA') {
                        console.log("PA");

                        pending++;
                    }
                    else if (input.ActivationStatus == 'DE') {
                        console.log("DE");

                        desactive++;
                    }
                    //Contracting mode is independent of the ActivationStatus
                    if (input.ContractingMode == '2') {
                        console.log("Vodafone");

                        vodafone++;
                    }

                });

            })

        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject('There was an error')
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    });
```

The global result of each counter is `0`, the code doesn't increment the number. And I don't know how I can continue.

Comment: Is the GET-request successful? What's the content of `data`?

Comment: You are incrementing the counters, but you never use the value anywhere. Which code do you use to get the value and when/how is it called?

Comment: Yes, the data is okey. Now only i seeing the result with console.logs for see that it's work, but not is working

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the declaration of your counting variables out of the loop. Otherwise they will be declarated and initialized to 0 everytime you loop through.

Comment: Lol, can't believe that I didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the counters in the wrong scope/closure

```
}).success(function (data) {
  // declare these in the success
  var counters = { 'AC' : 0, 'PA': 0, 'DE': 0, 'Vodafone':0 }

  ...

  if (counters.hasOwnProperty(input.ActivationStatus)) {
    counters[input.ActivationStatus]++;
    console.log( input.ActivationStatus);
  }

  if (input.ContractingMode == '2') {
    console.log("Vodafone");
    counters.Vodafone++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you resolving the promise by calling `defer.resolve('...')` upon finish/success of promise? 
You should also declare the counter variables in the global scope of the execution and not inside the `input.forEach` iteration.

Answer (score 1):

also another way to calculate is

```
active = input.filter(function(i){
  return i.ActivationStatus == 'AC';
}).length;
```

Comment: Yes, but you're iterating over the data 4 times instead of just once if you use filters.

Answer (score 1):

Declare count variables outside the loop `input.forEach`. Every time they reinitialize the 0 value

Comment: That's the exact same answer @Thomas gave two minutes earlier